# Is there a solution to glitches when deleting features from shapefiles on network drives?

Tags: qgis

We are a small GIS department of 4 folks working with a shapefile composed of points.  We have local installs (C:) of QGIS 2.8.1 on our work stations, which run Windows 7 x64.  The shapefile in question is installed on a network drive.

Lately we have noticed that, only sometimes, deleting a single point causes the attributes of the remaining points to be replaced with those of the next record in the feature set.  For example, say we have 3 points, all with a field called "Label."  The labels of the 3 points are as follows: FOO.1, FOO.2, FOO.3.  I want to delete FOO.1, so I do so using the tool in QGIS whose icon is a red trash can, either in the map canvas or in the attribute table of the layer.  The point "FOO.1" is deleted from the map and the attribute table, but now the point "FOO.2" has the attributes of the point "FOO.1," and moves to the location of the deleted point.  This glitch seems to cascade down the attribute table, affecting all subsequent points in the layer and moving attributes from one record to another.

In searching for similar glitches to this one, our team has discovered a documented bug from 6 years prior that seems to replicate our situation:

[Delete feature bug](https://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/828#comment:2)

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't seem to suggest a solution for those folks like us who store their layers on a drive separate from the one where QGIS is installed.

I was wondering if anyone else has come across this documented bug during their workflow, and if so, they have found sustainable ways to work around it.  We have come up with a temporary solution to fix the problem of "rolled back" attributes, that is, loading the table as a .csv file and manually fixing the unique IDS associated with the features to accommodate the deleted record.  However, this is not a long-term solution.

If the only solution turns out to be that we need to temporarily move our layers to our local drives and only edit them there, that'd be just fine, but we want to make sure there isn't some other simpler or more elegant solution.

Comment: Did you place a comment on the bug asking developers for help as well?

Comment: In the long term you should probably look at using Postgresql/Postgis in the network drive and move your data to it, QGIS has native Postgis edit support and you can export to whatever format you need. I would suggest you file a bug in hub.qgis.org so developers can look at it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report rather than a question on StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

Bug reports generally need to be logged on the qgis site with screenshots and posibly sample data so that developers can try to replicate your error. In the meantime try to add the shapefile to spatialite and try to eliminate if it is a shapefile error. Vector>properties>save as>choose type as spatialite and try to replicate the behaviour then you can know its a bug